# python manage.py makemigrations gives attributeError: module 'django.views.debug' has no attribute 'TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE' error

Tags: python, node.js, django

I am setting my project as said in

[this project from github](https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-react-boilerplate)

Steps I took..

Started the project by this command
django-admin startproject theprojectname --extension py,yml,json --name Procfile,README.md,.env.example --template=https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-react-boilerplate/archive/boilerplate-release.zip

then i installed the pip packages

pip install -r requirements-to-freeze.txt
Saved them

pip freeze > requirements.txt

Ran the npm update commands

npm update --save
 npm update --save-dev

cp goDiary/settings/local.py.example goDiary/settings/local.py
cp .env.example .env
and after that

python manage.py makemigrations

And I have almost same code except that I refactored the name

After `making pip install -r requirements.txt`

And the output when I am making the migrations is this

Are my confs correct?

```
(myvenv2) shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/home/goDiary$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 27, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/goDiary/myvenv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fixmydjango/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    original_TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE = debug.TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE
AttributeError: module 'django.views.debug' has no attribute 'TECHNICAL_500_TEMPLATE'
```

This is my

> manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

from decouple import config


if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings_module = config('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', default=None)

    if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
        if settings_module:
            print("Ignoring config('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE') because it's test. "
                  "Using 'goDiary.settings.test'")
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "goDiary.settings.test")
    else:
        if settings_module is None:
            print("Error: no DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE found. Will NOT start devserver. "
                  "Remember to create .env file at project root. "
                  "Check README for more info.")
            sys.exit(1)
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings_module)

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

> My wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for goDiary project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.base")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: fixmydjango is your package?

Comment: @paradox fixmydjango is a 3rd party lib that helps describing django issues and suggesting fixes. It's in the boilerplate's requirements. I've answered the OP's question in the issue he's created at the boilerplate's github page, he probably installed the wrong version of django (it requires 1.11). See my answer below for more info, if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might fall into this same issue, the discussion is happening on the project's github page, at https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-react-boilerplate/issues/166

If you just want the answer, it's probably related to a wrong version of Django. Check if you've installed Django 1.11 and not Django 2.0 or some other version :)